# Rich makers for Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there any implementation of markers who allow the combinaison of those functionnalities :

- html content like gmaps-v3-label-marker (http://github.com/adammck/gmaps-v3-label-marker)
- work with clusterer (http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/simple_example.html). Based on marker and not OverlayView
- Infowindow available

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used finally dynamically generated images with all informations ! I works, but it's slow even with caching.

I someone have a better idea...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/examples/richmarker.html?